# Qt Dial передача сигнала с одной формы на другой

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, сигналы-слоты, qdial

Подскажите пожалуйста у меня есть 2 формы. Не знаю как передать сигнал от одного dial1 в Form1 в другой dial2 в Form2 (например двигаешь dail1 на Form1, на Form2 dial2 повторяет тоже самое действие).
Просто на одной форме это делается просто, а вот на двух голова не может сообразить.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: ну там же в connect указывается раздельно обьект для сигнала и объект для слота

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое окно. Генерируем значение (через сигнал):

```
class Window1 ... {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Window1(QWidget* parent=nullptr):... {
        ...
        connect(ui->dial1, &QDial::valueChanged, this, &Window1::dialValueChanged);
    }
signals:
    void dialValueChanged(int value);
}
```

Второе окно. Получаем и устанавливаем значение:

```
class Window2 ... {
    Q_OBJECT
...
public slots:
    void setDialValue(int value) {
        ui->dial2->setValue(value);
    }

}
```

Связь (Где-то, допустим в методе `main`):

```
int main(...) {
    ...

    Window1 win1;
    Window2 win2;
    // Соединяем и передаем значение из одного окна в другое
    QObject::connect(&win1, &Window1::dialValueChanged,
                     &win2, &Window2::setDialValue);

    win1.show();
    win2.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```